# In add filter criteria "user" not coming from FILTER list in add views

Tags: views

I am following the book "The Definitive Guide to Drupal 7" where I am trying to add a new view. But when I tried to add filter,I can't find the User in the FILER list . I am very beginner to Drupal,though I know PHP . [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what kind of view you're creating. You are probably working on a view for content. So the filters are limited to those related to content. You can add a relationship "Content: Author" (Relate content to the user who created it.) under "Advanced Options" to add more filter criteria to the filter criteria list (User will show up in the filter list then, too).

[image]

Or you try creating a view for users.

Comment: Thnk you Volker...I was googling this over 48hrs ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to go to "Add relationships" to Content: Author
Now go back to "Add filter criteria" and you will see the user filter and a lot more user information you can use.

This was a change from Views 2 to Views 3 I think.